# Why SlickGrid column picker hangs in Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, slickgrid

I'm trying to integrate SlickGrid in my Rails 3 application.

I use the latest Firefox on Windows XP.

Everything was fine until I added the column picker according to [this example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html).

Now, when I right click one of the header cells, I do see the column picker. But, when I click one of the check boxes, Firefox hangs.

Any ideas what could be the problem, or how to debug this ?

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed that if I remove the `width` parameter from all columns, everything works fine!

Comment: Can you post a repro on jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: I uploaded a "hang_example" here: http://rapidshare.com/files/449374591/slickgrid_hang_example.zip. It is the first (simple) example in the package with slight changes. If you check "Force Fit Columns" in the column picker, Firefox hangs. Please let me know if you have a fix for this.

Comment: In this "hang_example" if you check/uncheck the column check boxes in the column picker, it works as expected. In my application, however, Firefox hangs. I believe that these two problems related to each other. I hope if you fix the "Force Fit Columns" problem, my problem will also disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plug SlickGrid into static html not served by rails, does it still not work?

I suspect that this isn't an issue with Rails, unless the javascript isn't being loaded into your page.

Which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I tried to plug SlickGrid to static HTML (`public/slickgrid_test.html`) and static Javascript (`public/javascripts/slickgrid_test.js`), with exactly the same HTML and JS content that I have in the dynamic Rails files, but the result is the same (Firefox hangs). I use Firefox 3.6.13.

Comment: I tried also the same totally outside the Rails application. The result is the same, i.e. the problem is in SlickGrid!